# Error while installing BlackBerry Web Development Plug-in for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, eclipse-plugin, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I want to add the blackberry Web Development Plug-in for Eclipse.I am using the link:

Web - http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.6/web

but I am getting following error:

```
    Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: BlackBerry WebWorks Plug-in 2.5.1.201010291444-2 (net.rim.browser.tools.feature.feature.group 2.5.1.201010291444-2)
  Missing requirement: BlackBerry Web API Debugging SDK Plug-in 1.0.2.201010291444-17 (net.rim.browser.tools.ninja 1.0.2.201010291444-17) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime [3.6.0,3.7.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: BlackBerry WebWorks Plug-in 2.5.1.201010291444-2 (net.rim.browser.tools.feature.feature.group 2.5.1.201010291444-2)
    To: net.rim.browser.tools.ninja [1.0.2.201010291444-17]
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BlackBerry WebWorks Plug-in only allows to be installed on Eclipse 3.6.x(Helios). It doesn't support Eclipse 3.7(Indigo).

Comment: let me try in Eclipse 3.6.x(Helios) Thanks